# How can I rotate a Transform over a specified time in a single line of code?

Tags: unity, rotation, transformation

**How can I rotate a `Transform` over a specified time in a single line of code?**

I have had a lot of trouble with this in the past.  I wrote a script which rotates a `Transform` by a specified rotation over n seconds, or rotates a `Transform` towards a `Vector3` over n seconds, in a one liner.  I hope it helps others in the future.  See below.

Comment: I think the question is still good to have on the site, but it can remain closed as a duplicate. Alternatively, you can post your answer to the duplicate and I can up vote it there. Also, you're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script called `TransformExtentions`.  Paste the code into that script.

You can call `Transform.RotateTowardsOverTime(Vector3, float)` on your `Transform` where the `Vector3` is the target you want to rotate towards and the `float` is the number of seconds you want it to take.

You can call `Transform.RotateOverTime(Vector3, float)` on your `Transform` where the `Vector3` is the rotation you want to apply and the `float` is the number of seconds you want it to take.  You can apply rotations greater than 360 degrees or less than -360 degrees.

Calling `Transform.RotateTowardsOverTime(Vector3, float)` or `Transform.RotateOverTime(Vector3, float)` will cancel out any active rotation calls on the `Transform`.

If you pass in 0 seconds, the `Transform` will rotate infinitely.  If you pass in negative seconds, the `Transform` will rotate in reverse.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public static class TransformExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Rotates the transform to a specified rotation over a set number of seconds.
    /// For an infinite rotation, multiply the degrees by a float to adjust the speed, and set the duration to 0 seconds.
    /// Calling RotateOverTime() or RotateTowardsOverTime() will cancel any pending rotations on this transform.
    /// </summary>
    public static void RotateTowardsOverTime(this Transform transform, Vector3 degrees, float seconds)
    {
        Vector3 rotationToBeMade = degrees - transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        if (degrees.z > 270.0F && transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z < 90.0F)
        {
            rotationToBeMade.z = -(360.0F - degrees.z + transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
        }
        if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z > 270.0F && degrees.z < 90.0F)
        {
            rotationToBeMade.z = 360.0F - transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z + degrees.z;
        }
        RotateOverTime(transform, rotationToBeMade, seconds);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rotates the transform by a specified number of degrees over a set number of seconds.
    /// For an infinite rotation, multiply the degrees by a float to adjust the speed, and set the duration to 0 seconds.
    /// Calling RotateOverTime() or RotateTowardsOverTime() will cancel any pending rotations on this transform.
    /// </summary>
    public static void RotateOverTime(this Transform transform, Vector3 degrees, float seconds)
    {
        RotateOverTime[] oldRotateOverTimeComponents = transform.gameObject.GetComponents<RotateOverTime>();
        foreach (RotateOverTime oldRotateOverTimeComponent in oldRotateOverTimeComponents)
        {
            GameObject.Destroy(oldRotateOverTimeComponent);
        }

        RotateOverTime rotateOverTimeComponent = transform.gameObject.AddComponent<RotateOverTime>();
        rotateOverTimeComponent.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideInInspector;
        rotateOverTimeComponent.Degrees = degrees;
        rotateOverTimeComponent.Seconds = seconds;
    }

class RotateOverTime : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 Degrees { get; set; }
    public float Seconds { get; set; }

    private Vector3 rotationCompleted = Vector3.zero;
    private Vector3 speed;
    private Vector3 startRotation;

    void Start()
    {
        speed = GetBalancedRotationSpeeds(Degrees, Seconds);
        startRotation = transform.eulerAngles;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        UpdateRotation();
        if (IsRotationComplete())
        {
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }

    private Vector3 GetBalancedRotationSpeeds(Vector3 degrees, float seconds)
    {
        if (seconds == 0)
        {
            seconds = 1;
        }
        float degreesWeight = (Degrees.x + Degrees.y + Degrees.z) / 3;
        float speedModifier = degreesWeight / seconds;
        float totalChangeInDegrees = Math.Abs(degrees.x) + Math.Abs(degrees.y) + Math.Abs(degrees.z);
        float xWeight = Math.Abs(degrees.x) / totalChangeInDegrees;
        float yWeight = Math.Abs(degrees.y) / totalChangeInDegrees;
        float zWeight = Math.Abs(degrees.z) / totalChangeInDegrees;
        float xSpeed = xWeight * speedModifier * 3;
        float ySpeed = yWeight * speedModifier * 3;
        float zSpeed = zWeight * speedModifier * 3;
        return new Vector3(xSpeed, ySpeed, zSpeed);
    }

    private void UpdateRotation()
    {
        rotationCompleted += Time.deltaTime * speed;
        Vector3 rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationCompleted + startRotation).eulerAngles;
        bool rotationIsValid = !(float.IsNaN(rotationCompleted.x) || float.IsNaN(rotationCompleted.y) || float.IsNaN(rotationCompleted.z) && float.IsNaN(startRotation.x) || float.IsNaN(startRotation.y) || float.IsNaN(startRotation.z) || float.IsNaN(rotation.x) || float.IsNaN(rotation.y) || float.IsNaN(rotation.z));
        if (!rotationIsValid)
        {
            Destroy(this);
        }
        transform.eulerAngles = rotation;
    }

    private bool IsRotationComplete()
    {
        bool xRotationIsComplete = Math.Abs(rotationCompleted.x) >= Math.Abs(Degrees.x);
        bool yRotationIsComplete = Math.Abs(rotationCompleted.y) >= Math.Abs(Degrees.y);
        bool zRotationIsComplete = Math.Abs(rotationCompleted.z) >= Math.Abs(Degrees.z);
        return xRotationIsComplete && yRotationIsComplete && zRotationIsComplete && Seconds != 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but aren't quaternions used to do exactly that?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Rotating over a specified amount of time is very challenging in Unity in my experience, unless there is something new with Unity 5.  This script makes it a one liner.